# Enterprise Library 5 - Log exceptions to legacy database

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

My task is to hook up an El5 Logger to a legacy database, where the company's exceptions are logged.
I followed the instructions in this post:
[custom DB logging using enterprise library 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642749/custom-db-logging-using-enterprise-library-4-1)

Here is where I get stuck:

I copied the FormattedDatabaseTraceListener into my solution, changed the name to "MyDbTraceListener" and modified it to talk to my database. How do I get the EL5 framework to use my new Tracelistener? I can't pick it in the EL5 config designer, as it doesn't derive from CustomTraceListener.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extension APIs changed significantly in Entlib 5.0. Take a look at the [Enterprise Library Extensibility Hands-on labs](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13738) for details on creating various kinds of extensions, including trace listeners.

Comment: More specifically, Lab 02, starting p.24. Also, Lindan, please share your experience extending EntLib with us.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to get me started. I'm trying out the lab right now. Will get back to this thread tomorrow and tell you how it went.

Comment: Thanks to your pointers, I got it to work. I completed the lab starting on page 24. Then I created my own tracelistener the same way.
In the writelog-method I call the methods that write the stuff I need into my database.
For additional information that I needed, I used the "data" property of the exception to
to add them. There is a lot of space for improvement, but it works for now. Thanks for your help.